# What method to use(in OpenCV) to associate markers to proper bone structure?

Tags: opencv, marker, capture, motion

I'm trying to write a C++ program using Opencv library that will reconstruct 3d points from the corresponding 2d markers placed on human model.

But I've a question. How do commercial mocap(motion capture) industry figure out which markers belong to which bone structure?

What I mean by my last question is: lets suppose there are three markers placed on left upper arm. What method do they use to associate these three markers to left upper arm from frame to frame?

Because it could belong to right upper arm right or to any bones like front chest, femur etc.

So what process do they implement to differentiate between markers and place the right marker to proper bone structure?

Do they use optical flow, SIFT to track markers where in frame-1 the markers' are labelled for proper bones? But even if the mocap industry use this method, aren't these two methods very time consuming? I saw a video on you-tube. And there they associate and reconstruct markers in real-time.

Is it possible to kindly tell me what procedure commercial mocap industry follow to correspond points to individual parts of skeleton structure?

After all you need to do this because you have to write the xRot, yRot and zRot(rotation about x-y-z axis) of bones in .bvh file so that you can view the 2d motion in 3d.

So what's the secret?

Answer (score 0):

For motion capture or tracking objects with markers in general the way to go is to keep track of the markers themselves between two frames and to keep track of the distance between the markers. A combination of this information is used to determine if a marker is the same as one close by to a marker in the previous frame.

Also these systems often use multiple cameras and have calibration objects where the position of markers is known and the correlation between the cameras can be determined. The algorithms to do this detection are highly advanced in these commercial mocap solutions.